# iAds banner doesn't show on device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, device, iad

I'm building an app with iAd banners. On simulator everything goes well but if I test my app on device, not a single delegate method is called and, obviously, no iAd banner is showed.

I've heard that is maybe because is a test app and the iAd feature needs to be set up in iTunes Connect to work. So, why does exist the developer settings : "iAd developer app testing" ? Is it possible to display iAd banner on test device ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set up in iTunes connect if you just want to test iAd.
But you do need to handle the case that if iAd fails to load, you can simply hide it, or choose to load other ads such as AdMob's ads.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix my problem before:

1. Make sure the date and time are correct
2. Reset the iAd delegate to self
3. Import the header from iAd

In your .h

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
```

In your .m (perhaps in viewDidLoad)

```
myAdBannerView.delegate = self;
```

And try fetching errors using:

```
NSLog(@"error banner failed :\n%@", error);
```

in your didFailToRecieveAdWithError

Comment: It was the `myAdBannerView.delegate = self;` which really messed me up